# Confirmation email from PHP form

Tags: php, forms

I have a php form that works great. The confirmation email go to user but I want it to post there name before the message. It wont post the name right now. Just posts the message. I want it to say something like., Thank you FULL_Name (Then message) Any help would rock.

```
// Subject of confirmation email.

 $conf_subject = 'Test Message';



 // Who should the confirmation email be from?

 $conf_sender = 'Test <no-reply@test.com>';

 $msg .= $_POST['Full_Name']."\n";

 $msg = "Thank you for your recent inquiry If you have any questions please call us at 555-555-5555  \n\n";



 mail( $_POST['Email_Address'], $conf_subject, $msg, "From: $conf_sender" );
```

Comment: Remove the first dot in `$msg .= $_POST['Full_Name']."\n";` and put it in the other `$msg = "Thank you for...`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you just need to insert a variable into a string.

```
$name = $_POST['Full_Name'];

$msg = "Thank you ".$name." for your recent inquiry If you have any questions please call us at 555-555-5555  \n\n";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're adding the full_name to $msg. and then you replace the content of the variable with the message:

```
 $msg .= $_POST['Full_Name']."\n";

 $msg = "Thank you for your recent inquiry If you have any questions please call us at 555-555-5555  \n\n";
```

In this code you're first setting $msg with the full_name, and then adding the rest of the message.

```
 $msg = $_POST['Full_Name']."\n"; 

 $msg .= "Thank you for your recent inquiry If you have any questions please call us at 555-555-5555  \n\n";
```